# Whole loop taking longer than its iterations summed

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization, arm

we've run into a peculiar problem when profiling a certain part in our code.

```
auto timeSum = 0ul;
auto tOuterBeg = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
for (auto& camera : cameras) {
  auto tInnerBeg = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  // read camera frame and process it
  auto tInnerEnd = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  timeSum += std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(tInnerEnd - tInnerBeg).count();
}
auto tOuterEnd = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
auto outerDur = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(tOuterEnd - tOuterBeg).count();
std::cout << "inner: " << timeSum << " outer: " << outerDur << "\n";
```

Outer duration comes out as a much larger number, the difference is up to 14 milliseconds, which is a lot when one measurement is 27 milliseconds and the other one is 41 milliseconds. The code runs on an ARM processor and is cross-compiled using GCC 7, optimized (O3) build. We've tried minimizing the number of threads our program uses, but we couldn't see any change and we've run out of ideas as to what could be the cause here. Any ideas pointing to the possible cause are welcome.

EDIT:
std::high_resolution_clock should have much larger precision than milliseconds. In addition I tried replacing the loop with blocks for each camera as such:

```
auto timeSum = 0ul;
auto tOuterBeg = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
{
  auto tInnerBeg = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  // read and process camera 1
  auto tInnerEnd = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  timeSum += std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(tInnerEnd - tInnerBeg).count();
}
auto t1_ = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
{
  auto tInnerBeg = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  // read and process camera 2
  auto tInnerEnd = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  timeSum += std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(tInnerEnd - tInnerBeg).count();
}
auto t2_ = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
{
  auto tInnerBeg = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  // read and process camera 3
  auto tInnerEnd = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  timeSum += std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(tInnerEnd - tInnerBeg).count();
}
auto t3_ = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
{
  auto tInnerBeg = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  // read and process camera 4
  auto tInnerEnd = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  timeSum += std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(tInnerEnd - tInnerBeg).count();
}
auto tOuterEnd = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
auto outerDur = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(tOuterEnd - tOuterBeg).count();
auto outsideBlockSum = (t1_ - tOuterBeg) + (t2_ - t1_) + (t3_ - t2_) + (tOuterEnd - t3_);

std::cout << "inner: " << timeSum << " outer: " << outerDur << " outside block parts sum: " << outsideBlockSum "\n";
```

To rule out any clock imprecisions - timeSum and outsideBlockSum are equal, while timeSum is several milliseconds lower.

EDIT2: As @RobertAndrzejuk pointed out, destructors are called after the duration addition inside the loop. It was a bit trickier as we were creating a std::shared_ptr and feeding it to a data provider, which further distributes it to the program, so normally the shared_ptr's deletes gets called in a consumer thread. However, three of the four cameras did not have any subscribers and the way it was implemented, the shared_ptr's deleter got called in the processing thread.

Comment: Maybe your implementation of [std::chrono::high_resolution_clock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock) is not accurate enough.

Comment: There are multiple reasons imaginable: 1. the actual resolution of clock which may only count in some kind of discrete quantities 2. the parts which are not in inner but in outer time measurement (e.g. the inner time measurement itself and the looping) 3. floating point arithmetics may be an issue as well (though a minor IMHO).

Comment: A physics teacher of mine (when I was a school boy) was used to say: Who measures measures wrong. ;-)

Comment: There is a timing overhead associated with machinery of the loop itself, to iterate over `cameras`, that will not be counted by the timing within the loop.   Also every call of `high_resolution_clock::now()` does actually have a non-zero duration and can have a significant granularity.    Without a [mcve] it is not possible to even guess what the differences should be.

Comment: Destructors are called after you have calculated timeSum.

Comment: Forget about the _floating point issues_. All these `auto`s were misleading me...

Comment: @Peter I'd love to provide such example, but as there's code reading and processing camera frames using non-free libraries, I don't see a way to do it.

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk Thank you, it was a destructor after all. If you could post that as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your timing functions do not include the time taken by the destructors.

I would create a class which in it's constructor "starts the clock".
Then in the destructor it "stops the clock" and adds the duration to the total duration value.

Something like this:

```
class TimeThis
{
    unsigned long& time_sum;

    const std::chrono::time_point< std::chrono::steady_clock > start;

public:
    TimeThis(unsigned long& time_sum)
          : time_sum(time_sum), start(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now())
    {}
    ~TimeThis()
    {
        const auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        time_sum +=
              std::chrono::duration_cast< std::chrono::milliseconds >(end - start).count();
    }
};
```

Then in the loop which You are doing You can call it (the first thing, so it's destructor is the last one called - destructors are called in opposite order of all the objects created):

```
for (auto& camera : cameras) {
    TimeThis t(timeSum);
  // read camera frame and process it
}
```

Another way is to create a function which takes a lambda and times around the execution of the lambda.

There are many ways in which to do this.

Comment: That's pretty neat. In our case this mistake in measuring and the durations not adding up led us to the core problem, which was trying to publish the data even without any subscribers, but I'll be sure to adopt a variation of your utility class. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Here is a short variant of your code:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    auto tOuterBeg = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto timeSum = 0ul;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 10000 ;++i) {
          auto tInnerBeg = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
          auto tInnerEnd = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
          timeSum += std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(tInnerEnd - tInnerBeg).count();
    }
    auto tOuterEnd = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto outerDur = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(tOuterEnd - tOuterBeg).count();
    std::cout << "inner: " << timeSum << " outer: " << outerDur << "\n";
}
```

On wandbox with GCC (8.2.0 with -O2) this prints :

```
inner: 0 outer: 26
```

But that huge difference is only because milliseconds are too coarse for timing the loop. With `chrono::microseconds` things are better:

```
inner: 10462 outer: 23960
```

This is still not good, but it is still much better than before.
Next, is the fact that there are two calls to `high_resolution_clock::now()` in each iteration. The `timeSum` times only one of the calls to `now()`, but `outerDur` counts both. This explains why `outer` displays roughly twice the amount of `inner`.

If you change the loop to call `high_resolution_clock::now()` only once per iteration, then the the difference between `outerDur` and `timeSum` will be much smaller:

```
auto tInnerBeg = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
for (int i = 0 ; i < 10000 ;++i) {
      auto tInnerEnd = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
      timeSum += std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(tInnerEnd - tInnerBeg).count();
      tInnerBeg = tInnerEnd;
}
```

The output of this is much closer to what you'd expect:

```
inner: 10817 outer: 12912
```

The difference can be further eliminated by moving to nanoseconds. It seems that the rounding of microseconds introduces too much errors:

```
inner: 13612956 outer: 13614153
```

The small difference is due to the cost of `duration_cast` and the loop itself.

Overall, it seems that on the wandbox machine, a single call to `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()` takes 1.361 microseconds. Take that into account.

## EDIT

Seeing the edit of the question, I have to agree with Robert Andrzejuk that for a small iteration count of just 4, the issue is probably time spent in destructors. To count in the destructors you can collect the timing after the destructors are run by putting the code in separate and inner block of `{}`:

```
auto tInnerBeg = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
for (int i = 0 ; i < 10000 ;++i) {
      {
         ////////////////////////
         // the timed code goes here
         //////////////////////////
      }
      auto tInnerEnd = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
      timeSum += std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(tInnerEnd - tInnerBeg).count();
      tInnerBeg = tInnerEnd;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as you say yourself, a call to std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() takes approximately 1-2 microseconds, while in my case the difference was several milliseconds.

Comment: @JakubJůza assuming that the loop had several thousands of iterations, this accumulates to milliseconds. Look at the code in the answer, it gives around 26 milliseconds difference

Comment: While not visible in my original question, in my first edit you can see that I'm actually looping over four cameras, I described the cause in my second edit.

Comment: @JakubJůza I have taken the code from your edit, and I can't reproduce the case for such a small iteration count of 4 cameras. I see a difference of only 10 microseconds. As Robert Andrzejuk has mentioned, if the number of iterations is small, then it could be an issue of where the destructors are called. I can't see any other reason for it to be like that